# Generating group ID for complicated matches

Tags: r

I have the following dataframe

```
> df <- data.frame(a = c('x', 'y', 'z', 't', 'm', 'n'), b = c('x', 'x', 'y', NA, 'm', 'm')) 
> df
  a    b
1 x    x
2 y    x
3 z    y
4 t <NA>
5 m    m
6 n    m
```

For every value, I'm trying to see if it exists in another row in the dataframe. If it exists, I'd like to add it to a group. All matches should also be added to that group.

In the above table, the first three rows should all be put in the same group. Since, row 1 should match row 2 and row 2 matches row 3.

My desired output then is:

```
> df
  a    b group
1 x    x     1
2 y    x     1
3 z    y     1
4 t <NA>    NA
5 m    m     2
6 n    m     2
```

I can imagine a for loop but I have too many rows for that. I've been trying to vectorise it, however my syntax is just way too slow even for the most basic of matches.

Been trying to use the following but `b[.x] %in% b[-.x]` doesn't run with my amount of rows.

```
df %>%
  mutate(xx = map_chr(row_number(), function(.x) {
  if (b[.x] %in% b[-.x]){
    return("match")
  } else {
    return(NA)
  }} ))
```

Comment: Why don't you assigne a group to `t`, `NA` row? it could be a single group. Would it be a problem in that case?

Comment: Why row4 output is `NA` instead of allocating it its own group id?

Comment: @AnilGoyal I think we should.

Comment: If you are uanble to get from linked question - use this after loading `igraph` and `tidyverse` `graph.data.frame(df) %>% components() %>% pluck(membership) %>% stack() %>% set_names(c('Group', 'a')) %>% right_join(df, by = c('a'))`

Comment: Allocating its own group_id makes more sense, thanks! The igraph and linked question should get me there! :)